# Why does adding a stateful widget to the end of the list of TabItems call initState and dispose?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a defaultTabController that displays Tabs and a TabBarView based on a list of TabItem(title, widget) where the title is for the title in the Tab and widget is a stateful widget to display in the TabBarView.

Whenever I widgetList.add() a new TabItem to this list of TabItem, the initState() and dispose() of that stateful widget is called. But when I widgetList.insert it doesn't.

Just curious why does this only happen whenever it's added to the end of the list.

Here is a DartPad that shows this off. Just comment and uncomment accordingly when trying out widgetList.add and widgetList.insert:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=d84d7236a50c0c4769427fcc8b287f41&null_safety=true

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had observed considering different scnarios.

1. widgetList is empty and using add

```dart
List<TabItem> widgetList = [];
..
// added this count to check which widget is calling init or dispose
widgetList.add(TabItem("Added", AWidget(count: count)));
```

- Initial: No Widget
- First press: Adds the widget (prints init 0)
- Second press: Adds another widget (prints init1 dispose1)
- Further presses: Doesn't print anything

2. widgetList containing 3 tabs and using add

```dart
List<TabItem> widgetList = [];
..
// added this count to check which widget is calling init or dispose
List<TabItem> widgetList = [
    TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 0)),
    TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 1)),
    TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 2))
  ];
```

- Initial: Contains 2 tabs (prints init0)
- Further presses: Doesn't print anything

3. widgetList is empty and using insert

```dart
List<TabItem> widgetList = [];
..
// added this count to check which widget is calling init or dispose
widgetList.insert(count, TabItem("Added", AWidget(count: count)));
```

- Initial: No Widget
- First press: Adds the widget (prints init 0)
- Second press: Adds another widget (prints init1 dispose1)
- Further presses: Doesn't print anything

4. widgetList containing 3 tabs and using insert

```dart
List<TabItem> widgetList = [
    TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 0)),
    TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 1)),
    TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 2))
  ];
..
// added this count to check which widget is calling init or dispose
widgetList.insert(count, TabItem("Added", AWidget(count: count)));
```

- Initial: Contains 2 tabs (prints init0)
- Further presses: Doesn't print anything

Considering all the 4 cases: You get the `init` and `dispose` only once i.e. when there is only 1 tab present and you are adding 2nd tab. It is because the added tab initialises when added to the `TabBar` and immediately disposes.

I assume that the tab bar initialises the (intended) functionality when it 2nd tab is added and then works fine when the rest are added.

> Typically a list of two or more Tab widgets.

My assumption was based on this statement from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/tabs.html).

What I can surely say is that this behaviour is caused by `TabBar` and not `List`.

`add` and `insert` works similar and doesn't have any affect on this behaviour.

Meanwhile, when you shift to other tabs let's say from 0->1. Then it prints, `init1`, `dispose0`. It is because when moving away from the widget, it initialises the new widget and disposes the previously used (just like a navigation activity).

I also want to point out one more thing. Consider using `add` instead of `insert` unless needed due to time complexity.

Full code I used to test (includes count):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabItem {
  final String title;
  final Widget widget;

  TabItem(this.title, this.widget);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<TabItem> widgetList = [];
  int _count = 0; // use 3 when using below commented code
  
//   List<TabItem> widgetList = [
//     TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 0)),
//     TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 1)),
//     TabItem("Test", const AWidget(count: 2))
//   ];

  void _incrementCounter(int count) {
    setState(() {
      widgetList.add(TabItem("Added", AWidget(count: count)));
//       widgetList.insert(count, TabItem("Added", AWidget(count: count)));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main Page'),
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: widgetList.length,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text("Press floating button to add to list"),
                bottom: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: <Tab>[
                    for (var i in widgetList)
                      Tab(
                        text: i.title,
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                  children: [for (var i in widgetList) i.widget]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _incrementCounter(_count++);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.count=0,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  final int count;

  @override
  _AWidgetState createState() => _AWidgetState();
}

class _AWidgetState extends State<AWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState ${widget.count}');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('dispose ${widget.count}');
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('something ${widget.count}');
  }
}
```